# How to convert arcpy.InsertCursor to arcpy.da.InsertCursor in Python code?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have some working code using `arcpy.InsertCursor` which I want to convert to `arcpy.da.InsertCursor`. This I want to do primarily as ESRI claims that `da` methods are more optimized. The code I have is follows:

```
array = arcpy.Array()
point = arcpy.Point()
tie_shp_file = arcpy.env.workspace + "/" + out_name
insert_cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(tie_shp_file)
feat = insert_cursor.newRow()

for line in all_lines:   #all_lines is of the form array([[0, 3],[0, 7],[1, 3]) indicating line [from, to]
    #from
    point.X=coords_pts[str(pt[line[0]])][0]
    point.Y=coords_pts[str(pt[line[0]])][1]
    array.add(point)
    #to
    point.X=coords_pts[str(pt[line[1]])][0]
    point.Y=coords_pts[str(pt[line[1]])][1]
    array.add(point)
    polyline=arcpy.Polyline(array)# Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
    array.removeAll() #Clear the array
    feat.shape = polyline
    insert_cursor.insertRow(feat)
```

The code inserts lines to a line shapefile. The lines are created by specifying its end points.

How do I convert this? I am specifically stuck on how to pass the to and from points in the new version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key difference between "classic" cursors like [`arcpy.InsertCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000002z000000) and the new cursors like [`arcpy.da.InsertCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) is that the list of field names to search, update, or insert is now a required parameter, where it was only optional before. This parameter should be passed as a list of string objects. In order to search, update, or insert geometry, you need to use one of the `SHAPE` tokens: `SHAPE@` will allow for full read/write access to the geometry of the feature.

For `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` specifically, there is no longer a `newRow()` method. Instead, you just pass a list of objects corresponding to the field names you specified in the `arcpy.da.InsertCursor`.

Here's how you would change your code:

```
array = arcpy.Array()
point = arcpy.Point()
tie_shp_file = arcpy.env.workspace + "/" + out_name
insert_cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(tie_shp_file,["SHAPE@"]) #Editing only geometry field

for line in all_lines:   #all_lines is of the form array([[0, 3],[0, 7],[1, 3]) indicating line [from, to]
    #from
    point.X=coords_pts[str(pt[line[0]])][0]
    point.Y=coords_pts[str(pt[line[0]])][1]
    array.add(point)
    #to
    point.X=coords_pts[str(pt[line[1]])][0]
    point.Y=coords_pts[str(pt[line[1]])][1]
    array.add(point)
    polyline=arcpy.Polyline(array)# Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
    array.removeAll() #Clear the array
    insert_cursor.insertRow([polyline]) #Pass list with polyline to insert cursor.
```

You can see how the `[polyline]` list used in the `insertRow` method corresponds to the `["SHAPE@"]` list in the cursor's constructor. If you needed to insert additional fields, they would have to be passed in corresponding order.